# there is an issue in filtering my expenses array

Tags: reactjs

I am making a simple expense tracker using react and all my functionality is currently in the app component.
I filtered the expenses array to select the expenses from the selected year and render it below in the ul and li tag by mapping the filtered array.
But on adding the new expense and choosing the date, my app logs an error at the filter function that expense.date.getFullYear() is not a function, which I'm not able to figure out why, and need help with the same.

Below is the code for my app

`

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

// dummy expenses array
const DUMMY_EXPENSES = [
  {
    id: "e1",
    title: "Toilet Paper",
    amount: 94.12,
    date: new Date(2020, 7, 14),
  },
  { id: "e2", title: "New TV", amount: 799.49, date: new Date(2021, 2, 12) },
  {
    id: "e3",
    title: "Car Insurance",
    amount: 294.67,
    date: new Date(2021, 2, 28),
  },
  {
    id: "e4",
    title: "New Desk (Wooden)",
    amount: 450,
    date: new Date(2021, 5, 12),
  },
];

function App() {
  // state to store the expenses in an Array
  const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState(DUMMY_EXPENSES);

  // state to select filtered year
  const [filteredYear, setFilteredYear] = useState("2020");

  // state to check if form is being edited or not
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);

  // states for inputs of form
  const [inputTitle, setInputTitle] = useState("");
  const [inputDate, setInputDate] = useState("");
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState("");

  // form input change functions
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setInputTitle(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleDateChange = (e) => {
    setInputDate(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleAmountChange = (e) => {
    setAmount(e.target.value);
  };

  // form submit functionality
  const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newExpense = {
      title: inputTitle,
      date: inputDate,
      amount: amount,
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000),
    };

    setExpenses((prevExpense) => {
      return [newExpense, ...prevExpense];
    });
  };

  const showForm = () => {
    setIsEditing(true);
  };

  const hideForm = () => {
    setIsEditing(false);
  };

  // handling the filtered year change
  const handleYearChange = (e) => {
    setFilteredYear(e.target.value);
  };

  // filtering the expenses array according to the filteredYear
  const filteredExpenses = expenses.filter((expense) => {
    return expense.date.getFullYear().toString() === filteredYear;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {/* form for input of expense data */}
      {!isEditing && <button onClick={showForm}>Add Expense</button>}
      {isEditing && (
        <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
          <div className="new-expense__controls">
            <div className="new-expense__control">
              <label>Title</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                value={inputTitle}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="new-expense__control">
              <label>Amount</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                onChange={handleAmountChange}
                value={amount}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="new-expense__control">
              <label>Date</label>
              <input
                type="date"
                onChange={handleDateChange}
                value={inputDate}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="new-expense__actions">
              <button type="button" onClick={hideForm}>
                Cancel
              </button>
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      )}

      {/* filter by year functionality */}
      <div className="expenses-filter">
        <div className="expenses-filter__control">
          <label>Select Year</label>
          <select value={filteredYear} onChange={handleYearChange}>
            <option value="2023">2023</option>
            <option value="2022">2022</option>
            <option value="2021">2021</option>
            <option value="2020">2020</option>
            <option value="2019">2019</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* rendering the list of expenses */}
      {filteredExpenses.map((expense) => {
        return (
          <li key={expense.id}>
            <div className="expense-item">
              <div className="expense-date">
                <div className="expense-date__month">
                  {expense.date.toLocaleString("en", { month: "long" })}
                </div>
                <div className="expense-date__year">
                  {expense.date.getFullYear()}
                </div>
                <div className="expense-date__day">
                  {expense.date.toLocaleString("en", { day: "2-digit" })}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="expense-item__description">
                <h2>{expense.title}</h2>
                <div className="expense-item__price">${expense.amount}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Update new expense as below, the reason, it does not accept the given Date as a **Date object**, it looks like as string, and therefore, need to convert it first Date.

```
   const newExpense = {
      title: inputTitle,
      date: new Date(inputDate),
      amount: amount,
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000),
    };
```